# Prove if $n≥3$ and $n^2+ 1$ is prime, then the rightmost digit of $n$ is $0,4,$ or $6$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $n≥3$ and $n^2+ 1$ is prime, then the rightmost digit of $n$ is $0,4,$ or $6$.

---

What I tried so far :

Since it's asking for 'rightmost digit', I guess it's about reminder of $\mod 10$

Proof.

Let $n\in[3,\infty)\cap\mathbb{N}$

Assume $n^2+1$ is prime

Show $\exists c\in\{0,4,6\},s.t. n^2+1\equiv c (\text{mod }10)$

That $$\text{WTS }\exists c\in\{0,4,6\},k\in\mathbb{N},s.t. n^2+1-c=10k$$

By assumption

$$\forall i\in\mathbb{N},i\mid n^2+1\rightarrow i\in\{1,n^2+1\}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\forall i\in\mathbb{N},\exists j\in\mathbb{Z},s.t. n^2+1=ji\rightarrow i\in\{1,n^2+1\}$$
Maybe try contradiction
$$\forall c\in\{0,4,6\},k\in\mathbb{N},s.t. n^2+1-c\neq10k$$
$$\vdots$$

---

Any help or hint or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try to prove the contraposition: If $n \ge 3$ is odd or $n \in n\{2,8\} \mod 10$, then $n^2 + 1$ is composite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last digit of the square of any number belongs to (0,1,4,5,6,9)
We can eliminate all odd digits as that number +1 would make it even which would make it composite. The set of possible last digits becomes (0,4,6). Also, 4+1 would give 5 which is itself prime but since $n{\gt}3$, 5 wont be an output and all numbers greater than 5 ending with 5 are composite. That leaves us with (0,6). The only numbers which give 0 or 6 when squared are 0,4 and 6. Hence proved.

Comment: The OP is asking about the rightmost digit of $n$, not the rightmost digit of $n^2$.

Comment: No he is right since n^2 have rightmost  digits 0,6 n must have rightmost digits 0,4,6